# Not allowed "-" character in a controller file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I downloaded via composer package that has character "-" in the name. Then I get error when I try to use it

```
  use Marekweb\Opaque-id\OpaqueEncode;
```

error:

```
  syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ',' or ';'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you've came with this namespace, but `OpaqueEncoder` class simply [doesn't have one](https://github.com/marekweb/opaque-id/blob/bc6d58040fb208ada2ab1c62fea29647b06a2342/OpaqueEncoder.php) (thus residing in root namespace), you simply write `use OpaqueEncoder` to import it in non-root namespace.

Update. **It doesn't have any namespace at all**

```
namespace Xyz\Anything;

use OpaqueEncoder;

class ABC
{
    public function dunno($key)
    {
        $encoder = new OpaqueEncoder($key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is "OpaqueEncoder", typo error, but there is the same error if I set path to the file Marekweb\Opaque-id\OpaqueEncoder. I am always getting syntax error.

Comment: @gormit **There is no namespace at all**, you should not use `Marekweb\Opaque-id\` portion at all, please read carefully. I've updated answer with a simplest example.

Comment: I don't have a problem when I create alias and "use OpaqueEncoder;", only when write full path

Comment: @gormit There is no "full path". This class resides in root namespace, thus FQCN of it would be simple `\OpaqueEncoder`, and backwards slash is omittable in `use` statements. There is no `namespace` statement in this class file, you may check it on github yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
I don't know the syntax, but the following guesses might help:
  - the backward slashes, should they be forward slashes?
  - maybe a missing semi-colon on the previous line.
  - the '-' might not be the right '-' but rather some other dash.
    you could try deleting and retyping it.
  - character encoding mismatch, utf-8 vs Cp???? (or whatever)
  - character encoding not declared at top of document or in whatever 
    meta placeholder or pragma the language provides.
  - check the actual encoding of your document.
You might get lucky. :)
```